# Shortcut to change keyboard layout doesn't work

Tags: release-freya, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I read about <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> keyboard Shortcut to change the keyboard layout, but it is not working, despite being defined in System Settings. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you changed any settings? try to reassign: settings --> keyboard --> universal access --> here select "Next keyboard layout ", press Alt+Space. Please let me know :)

Comment: @Ravan It does not help. All is same, shortcut doesn't work. Freya is fully updated.

Comment: Are you sure those two keys are working?

Comment: Absolutely sure, if you mean that keyboard recognized them. Keys are working, but nothing change... :(

Comment: try to create custom shortcut and let me know :)

Comment: Wow, it works! Shift+Space worked. But what's up with Alt+Space?

Comment: thats fine, :) I need to know o_O.

Comment: have you tried reboot?

Comment: I had this a while ago. Long story short, there's a default action with shortcut alt-space (I can't remember which) that conflicts. You just have to disable this with dconf-editor and problem solved. Will see if I can find out which one it was later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> may be problems, but you can change <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in System Settings (Switchboard). This combination does not fail, and works without problems.

Also you can set some other combinations that are not available from Switchboard.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L', '<Alt>Shift_R', '<Shift>Alt_L', '<Shift>Alt_R']"
```

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Ctrl>Shift_L', '<Ctrl>>Shift_R', '<Shift>Control_L', '<Shift>Control_R']"
```

<kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings switch-input-source "['Caps_Lock']"
```

Comment: why Alt+Space have problem?, OP already changed to custom [shortcut](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/altspace-doesnt-work#comment5512_3124)

Comment: @Ravan alt+space sometimes doesn't work, for example after kernel upgrade.

Comment: sounds logical, can you confirm [this](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3124/altspace-doesnt-work/3146?noredirect=1#comment5539_3125)

Answer (score 0):

While solving this issue, I messed up something in dconf and results  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> stopped working. The shortcut working with other combinations.(Even I have set all settings to : Default Settings)

Finally *reboot* solved the issue.

Comment: Strange... I don't recall ever modifying something in dconf. I don't know if dconf-editor is installed at all!

Comment: Oh, and, by the way, Alt+Space works when I made it "Previous Keyboard Layout" shortcut.

Comment: @Fireburn I observed one point, but I can't confirm it : When Alt+Space stops working, "Reassaign working for me "

Answer (score -1):

I found another work around by binding 'Previous Keyboard Layout' to Alt+Space. It works fine.