# Keyboard Layout shortcut conflict

Tags: release-freya, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I read [THIS](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3146/1181) answer that was really good on how to change the keyboard layout with Left Ctrl + Left Shift, but when I use

> Ctrl Shift C (to copy on terminals)
>
> and Ctrl Shift V (to paste on terminals)

the keyboard layout changes and I cannot perform the copy/paste action. In Elementary Luna, which I had previously, It would only change the Layout ON KEY UP. Hence, it would not conflict with Ctrl + Shift + (whatever key). And on Freya, according to that answer, it is ON KEY DOWN.

Is there any chance to make it work like Luna, and the key combination Left Shift + Left Ctrl take effect only ON KEY UP?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using **modifiers** (<kbd>shift</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>super</kbd>) is that they are modifiers, and not designed to actually change something themselves. I would suggest that a far easier fix would be to simply assign the shortcut to , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or something similar. Basically, **include a non-modifier key** in all your shortcuts.

Comment: Thing is: It worked on Elementary Luna. I'd like it to behave the same way. It is possible.

Comment: It also works in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but doesn't work in Elementary Loki. So using alternative shortcuts is not a solution. I prefer Ctrl+Shift.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that shortcut works on key press than key release. You are using `Ctrl + Shift` to language change. The linked post also have option `Shift + Alt`.

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.gala.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift_L', '<Alt>Shift_R', '<Shift>Alt_L', '<Shift>Alt_R']"
```

Use it and you can avoid conflict.

Comment: I also prefer to use Ctrl+Shift over Shift+Alt. So using Shift+Alt instead doesn't answer the question.